# How do I properly use Sow and Reap within a Do loop?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, modeling

The problem is that reap only returns one value when I was expecting a string resulting from Do.

For context:

This is a simple democratic deficiency model. Where m is the 
number of periods, n is the number of voters,and r is the frequency 
of elections. c is the table which represents the preferences of 
voters, currently random. v is the rule which determines the policy 
set by the government based on the simple average of preferences. 
mode is the function which sets elections. e is a dummy variable for 
elections. u is a placeholder vector. g is the function which allows 
the government to update policies in election years. dgpcpp is the 
democratic deficiency generated by the current government per person 
per year. I would like to run this program multiple (maybe 100) times for 
varying values of r and plot the values of dgpcpp. Eventually I would also like to add a function of interaction between voters which replaces RandomnInteger in how their preferences are determined. Finally would like to give each individual a vector of preferences so that I could compare this model with an indirect (first past the post) voting model where preferences determine candidate selection.

```
 Do[m = 10;
 n = 5;
 r = 4;
 c = RandomInteger[1, {m, n}];
 avg = Total[c, {2}]/n;
 v = If[0.5 <= # <= 1, 1, 0] & /@ avg;
 de = Abs[v - avg];
 Total[de];
 depcpp = Total[de]/n/m;
 mode = Mod[r - 1 + Range[m], r];
 e = If[# == 0, 1, 0] & /@ mode;
 u = RandomInteger[1, m];
 g = MapThread[If[#1 == 1, #2, #3] &, {e, v, u}];
 dg = Abs[g - avg];
 Total[dg];
 dgpcpp = Total[dg]/n/m; Sow[dgpcpp], {100}]
 Reap[dgpcpp]
 Total[dgpcpp]/r
```

Comment: Any use of `Sow[]` should really be within a `Reap[]`: `Reap[Do[(* stuff *); Sow[dgpcpp]; (* more stuff *)]]`.

Comment: Thank you! I must have misunderstood the documentation. Could you explain why the first result is null or how to change it so I can sum over the list?

Comment: Why don't you use `Table` instead of `Do`, `Sow` & `Reap`?

Comment: I am not sure how to make a table of tables. I would also like to learn a functional programming or pure function approach but am brand new to the software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try something very simple first

```
try1 = Do[dgcpp = n^2; Sow[dgcpp], {n, 4}]

Reap[try1]
(* {Null, {}} *)
```

Now `Null`, the output of `Do`, is returned as the first element and an empty list as the second element. Now try:

```
try2 = Reap[
  Do[dgcpp = n^2; Sow[dgcpp], {n, 4}]
  ]
(* {Null, {{1, 4, 9, 16}}} *)
```

Now `Null` is returned as the first element and the `Sow` values are a list within a list for the second element.

A slightly more functional approach

```
try3 = Reap[
  Scan[Sow[#^2] &, Range[4]]
  ]
(* {Null, {{1, 4, 9, 16}}} *)
```

produces a similar result.

Applying to your problem

```
dgpcppList = Reap[
  Scan[
   m = 10;
    n = 5;
    r = 4;
    c = RandomInteger[1, {m, n}];
    avg = Total[c, {2}]/n;
    v = If[0.5 <= # <= 1, 1, 0] & /@ avg;
    de = Abs[v - avg];
    Total[de];
    depcpp = Total[de]/n/m;
    mode = Mod[r - 1 + Range[m], r];
    e = If[# == 0, 1, 0] & /@ mode;
    u = RandomInteger[1, m];
    g = MapThread[If[#1 == 1, #2, #3] &, {e, v, u}];
    dg = Abs[g - avg];
    Total[dg];
    dgpcpp = Total[dg]/n/m;
    Sow[dgpcpp]; &,
   Range[100]
   ]
  ]
(* {Null, {{9/125, 11/125, 11/125, 21/250, 1/10, 11/125, 9/125, 
   29/250, 23/250, 23/250, 2/25, 13/125, 11/125, 1/10, 27/250, 2/25, 
   8/125, 11/125, 19/250, 23/250, 21/250, 3/25, 23/250, 27/250, 23/
   250, 2/25, 11/125, 23/250, 2/25, 21/250, 13/125, 1/10, 23/250, 11/
   125, 21/250, 2/25, 14/125, 2/25, 13/125, 2/25, 23/250, 12/125, 19/
   250, 23/250, 29/250, 23/250, 2/25, 3/25, 9/125, 21/250, 23/250, 1/
   10, 3/50, 13/125, 19/250, 12/125, 17/250, 12/125, 21/250, 8/125, 
   23/250, 11/125, 19/250, 12/125, 9/125, 2/25, 11/125, 17/250, 13/
   125, 1/10, 12/125, 19/250, 12/125, 9/125, 13/125, 12/125, 2/25, 12/
   125, 21/250, 12/125, 14/125, 2/25, 21/250, 9/125, 21/250, 21/250, 
   11/125, 12/125, 29/250, 13/125, 13/125, 12/125, 19/250, 19/250, 2/
   25, 2/25, 19/250, 1/10, 11/125, 19/250}}} *)
```

Now you can extract the interior of the second list and apply `Total` to get

```
Total@dgpcppList[[2, 1]]
(* 2227/250 *)
```

Comment: Thanks Jack very helpful. I will look into scan.