# Creating a numerical sequence with Do

Tags: code-review

I have the following code:

```
n = 10
nt = 2
ns = nt * n
inte = Range[n - 1]
Do[i = inte/n, {i, nt}]
```

I am trying to create a list that has the following result: 
1/n, 1/n, ... nt times, 2/n, 2/n, ... nt times until it reaches (n-1)/n, (n-1)/n, .... nt times.

I also tried:

```
For[i = 1, i <= nt, i++, Print[inte/n]]
```

that prints the result I want but I cant put into one single list. Can anyone give me some insight?

Comment: Look through the examples for [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html).  If you need to use `Do` instead, then you should use [`Reap` and `Sow`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134977/9490)

Comment: `Flatten[Table[k/n, {k, n - 1}, nt]]`

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 10;
nt = 2;
ns = nt*n;
inte = Range[n - 1];
```

There is no need to iterate, but it is not clear from your question whether you want

```
ConstantArray[inte/n, nt]
```

> `{{1/10, 1/5, 3/10, 2/5, 1/2, 3/5, 7/10, 4/5, 9/10}, 
>   {1/10, 1/5, 3/10, 2/5, 1/2, 3/5, 7/10, 4/5, 9/10}}`

which us what your For-loop suggests you want, or

```
ConstantArray[inte/n, nt] // Transpose // Flatten
```

> ```
> {1/10, 1/10, 1/5, 1/5, 3/10, 3/10, 2/5, 2/5, 1/2, 1/2, 
>  3/5, 3/5, 7/10, 7/10, 4/5, 4/5, 9/10, 9/10}
> ```

which is what your text description suggests.